# How to explain and show a new feature in a website?

Tags: coachmark

So, there is this website with news and other things, like the weather, horoscope, etc.. And there will be a new service where some news will be prime, the user will have to pay to see the article. I want to make something to introduce this new feature to the users, and I was thinking a coach mark, the first time the user enters and sees an article, it pops up a dark layer explaining what it is, and it doesn't appears again.

I wanted to know what are your opinions on this and if there is a better solution?

Comment: Hi Diana, let's see what your efforts are so far with this. This community works best when you show your efforts and explain some of your constraints. Do you have some mocks to show what your thinking is so far? What are some ways you're introducing the pay service? A button, link? summary of why they should pay?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like this:[image]

when people are reading the news don't want pop-ups showing everywhere, so something subtle might be useful.

another option is to add a banner in the site at the bottom of a news story or between the articles like this: [image]

The promotion for the new feature can be shown there.

or something even more subtle like calling the attention of your user to the section where the premium news are.

Comment: I think that is a good idea, but I want to be sure people will not think that now all the content is paid and will leave the website. I want to be sure people know that it's the same content but with more. I'm afraid that something subtle will be unnoticed.

Comment: Then again, Die welt might come handy, they put a small "Welt +" sign beside the news that are for premium subscription only, BUT also a pop up specifying what the premium subscription offers might be necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer again, 
It depends really on your situation, if you just need a feedback on a feature before you start working on it then I'd suggest to create a prototype for that feature so that people can see it in action and possibly interact with this.

Comment: I'm not sure how creating a prototype will help make people aware of a new feature of a site. The question isn't asking how they get feedback on a new feature, it's about how they make the users aware that the new feature exists.

Comment: Yes! exactly! I want people to understand the new feature and try it.